# Is it possible to register an .au domain without the .com?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, cctld

I am looking to register an Australian domain (`.au`), but I do want it to be `foo.au`, not `foo.com.au`.

Is it possible for a private business to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot register second-level .au domains.   Only [third-level domains may be registered](https://www.ausregistry.com.au/) in a small set of second-level categories such as

- .com.au
- .net.au
- .org.au
- .id.au
- .asn.au

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.au#Historic_second-level_domains):

> Some second-level domain names are no longer actively used. Whilst registrations are grand-fathered for some, no new registrations are accepted.

Registration of new second-level .au domains [has been proposed](https://www.auda.org.au/assets/pdf/2015npp-draft-recs.pdf), but it is unclear when those registrations will be available.

Comment: I have updated wikipedia to reflect my answer below

Answer (score 4):

Stephen Ostermiller is correct...at the moment.  However AuDa, the .au registrar has approved registration directly in the .au TLD

See this https://www.auda.org.au/news/auda-to-introduce-direct-registrations-in-au/

Comment: Nice.   Any idea when they will be available?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I am on the auda mailing list and there hasn't been an announcement beyond what is in the media release.  Generally these things move at a glacial pace.  However with climate change it might mean they speed up :P

Comment: @Steve Supposedly 24 March 2022 -- https://www.auda.org.au/au-domain-names/au-domain-names/au-direct-names/about-au-direct-domain-names

Answer (score 2):

We haven't heard anything specific about how the launch of direct registrations on .AU will go (sounds like they're still working on it), but recently .UK did the same thing. Direct registrations on .UK launched in June of 2014, but registrations of exact match domain names are restricted to those who own .CO.UK for the first 5 years. Basically, what this means is you couldn't register (using your example here) Foo.UK unless you already owned Foo.CO.UK. I'm telling you this because you may want to consider registering the domain name you want on .COM.AU now in case .AU decides to something similar. The article that Steve links to above does say that they are "taking into account the impact on existing registrants."

Here is more info about the UK restrictions, for your reference: http://www.theukdomain.uk/advice/do-i-have-uk-rights/

Answer (score 1):

As of today it is not possible to register .au second level domains, only third-level domains (.com.au, .NET.au, .org.au, etc).

Also I would like to mention that only Australian business or residents can register .au domain names.

Comment: Good to know it finally happened.    Where can they be registered?   Was there an announcement that you can link to?